# Will I benefit from taking animal beds in a caravan?

Tags: rimworld

When I go somewhere by caravan, I always remember to take bedrolls so my colonists will get a good night's sleep.  But this invariably leads to their sleep bars filling up quickly, followed by a long wait while the caravan animals finish sleeping as well.

What if I bring along some animal sleep beds?  Will the caravan animals use them to finish sleeping faster?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that animal beds like any other piece of furniture does not give any bonus unless placed. Bringing ordinary beds don't give any bonus either iirc. The main purpose of bringing bedrolls is to keep the mood of the travellers up.

Answer (score -1):

No.

Animals do not have a rest bar. Even on the colony, you gain nothing but decoration/organization/target place for healing, it does not affect your animals' "work hours".

Don't take them. You will increase the fuss and decrease your carrying capacity for nothing.

Comment: I'm a bit baffled at your assertion that animals don't have a rest bar.  Food and sleep are the two bars they have.  I asked the question because I noticed that my colonists are done resting while the animals are still slumbering away.

Comment: Although it's been long since I've used caravans, I never remember them doing anything else than start at 06:00 and stop at 22:00, regardless of animal (and even human) rest

Answer (score -2):

<s>I have been playing Rimworld for quite a while and animal beds serve the purpose of hospital beds basically but for animals.</s>

I do not think they serve any purpose beyond that.

As of version 1.3 Animal sleeping beds have rest efectiveness and can be used to increase the surgery success change. More info in the wiki https://rimworldwiki.com/wiki/Animal_bed